# Montecarlo in brightway2

Tags: montecarlo, brightway

I have problems running a Monte Carlo, and I am not sure where or what the problem is. A normal LCA calculation runs fine, and I checked that my exchanges have the uncertainty added.  I also tried to write the code in two different ways, but the problem is the same, the result is: `[nan, nan, nan]`

[image]

Below is the code that I am using

```
 mymethod1 = ('ReCiPe Midpoint (H) V1.13 no LT', 'climate change', 'GWP100')
 mymethod1

 el = t_db.get("chemical1 production")   
 functional_unit = {el: 1}
 lca = bw.LCA(functional_unit, mymethod1)
 lca.lci()
 lca.lcia()
 print(lca.score)

 mc = bw.MonteCarloLCA({el: 1}, mymethod1)  
 mc_results = [next(mc) for x in range(5)] 
 mc_results

 #also tried doing like this
 mc = bw.MonteCarloLCA({bw.Database('exldb').get('chemical1 production'):1}, 
 mymethod1) 
 next(mc)
 mc_results = [next(mc) for x in range(5)] 
 mc_results
```

Comment: without knowing what is inside _el_ or _mymethod1_ it is a bit difficult to catch the source of the problem. Can you write a reproducible example ? 

If not, if _el_ and _mymethod1_ were created by you, you can try to change them for an existing method or activity, to see if the problem comes from the activity, or the characterisation factors.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is in the inventory rather than the impact assessment method. I'd make sure you have all the parameters needed to define the probability distribution correctly defined. In the table [here](https://stats-arrays.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you can see what parameters need to be defined depending on the type of probability distribution you are using.

you can write:

```
import math as math

for Input,Output,Row,Col,Type,Uncertainty_Type,Amount,Loc,Scale,Shape,Min,Max,Negative in lca.tech_params:

if Uncertainty_Type in [0,1]:
    assert math.isnan(Loc) is False
    
    assert math.isnan(Scale) or (Scale is None)
    assert math.isnan(Shape) or (Shape is None)
    assert math.isnan(Min) or (Min is None)
    assert math.isnan(Max) or (Max is None)
    
elif Uncertainty_Type in [2,3]:
    # lognormal and normal
    assert math.isnan(Loc) is False
    assert math.isnan(Scale) is False
    
    assert math.isnan(Shape) or (Shape is None)

elif Uncertainty_Type == 4:
    # uniform
    assert math.isnan(Max) is False
    
    assert math.isnan(Loc) or (Scale is None),f" loc {Loc}"
    assert math.isnan(Scale) or (Scale is None)
    assert math.isnan(Shape) or (Shape is None)

elif Uncertainty_Type in [5,7]:
    # triangular and discrete uniform
    assert math.isnan(Max) is False

elif Uncertainty_Type in [8,9]:
    # weibull and Gamma
    assert math.isnan(Scale) is False
    assert math.isnan(Shape) is False
    
elif Uncertainty_Type in [10,11]:
    # beta, generalized extreme value
    assert math.isnan(Loc) is False
    assert math.isnan(Shape) is False
    
elif Uncertainty_Type == 12:
    # student
    assert math.isnan(Shape) is False
```

to check that all the uncertainty parameters are defined.

**update**: the stat-arrays repository warns against optional columns with values different to np.nan. I added a few assertions to check this.. and realised this is not the case for ecoinvent (3.6 consequential)

Comment: Before trying to run the Monte Carlo I checked that all my exchanges had the uncertainty declared, the only one that does not had it is for the first exchange which I declared as cero. Do you think that could be the problem? For the rest of the I used the code below to check that the exchanges were present.

Comment: I used  a log normal distribution and defined the loc= media and the scale=std deviation in the data base.                                                         
`[[print(exc.uncertainty) for exc in list(act.exchanges())]for act in t_db] `           
{'uncertainty type': 0, 'loc': 0.7, 'scale': 0.751915433, 'negative': False}
{'uncertainty type': 0, 'loc': 4.062, 'scale': 1.927553691, 'negative': False}
{'uncertainty type': 2, 'loc': 6.2, 'scale': 0.326598632, 'negative': False}
{'uncertainty type': 2, 'loc': 12638312.07, 'scale': 0.326598632, 'negative': False}

Comment: the stat-arrays repository has this warning: _Unused optional columns must be set to np.NaN to avoid unexpected behaviour!_ . I would try either remove or specify as np.nan the unused columns. For example in the first exchange you have the scale defined as a scalar value when it is not used.

Comment: if the response solved your question please consider accept it ;)

Comment: do you mean that when the uncertainty is cero set the loc and scale as np.nan?

Comment: yes, or simply not define them at all. For example, the uncertainty of your first exchange `{'uncertainty type': 0, 'loc': 0.7, 'scale': 0.751915433, 'negative': False}` should be `{'uncertainty type': 0, 'loc': 0.7}` there is no reason to define parameters that are not used by the distribution